# Threads in Flash and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, multithreading, concurrency

Are threads possible in Flash, Actionscript and Flex just like in C# and Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, [**there's no multithreading in Actionscript**](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=12026). However, you can fake it with pseudothreads (see [**link**](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=12026) for more details), although this has its own problems.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the present. You can use pseudo-threads if you want to. http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html